# Insert page with text to base64 pdf

Tags: php, pdf, base64, pdf-generation, laravel-6

everyone...!

There is a question that I've been trying to solve... so the question is... How can I insert a new page with text on an existing PDF, my code explanation is the next:

1.- I make a request to get an invoice and in the response I get the PDF invoice (as bas64 string) and the xml, and that's ok, it works.

2.- I have different ways to use the PDF and the xml: some times this items are send by email or downloaded by the user.

Now I need to insert a page with some text at the end of de PDF, I've been searching and found some PDF libraries for PDF generation, but I don't need to generate a new PDF document, I need to modify an existing document.

Someone knows any library or package to do this?
I'm a little confused with the info that I found... My proyecto is made with laravel 6

I found the FPDI package... but I'm confused about if is possible use it for the the task I need... if someone could help me, please!!

Comment: Hi @KJ!
Thanks for you comment (Y)!

Of course, I'm agree with you, the base64 string is text encoding, and in this form the pdf can't be manipulated.

The other way that you say is merge two pdf, the first is the invoice pdf and the second the information I want to add, I've tried this method but... I required a library to merge the pdf, in my localhost this solution works, but in the production server my provider denied me the possibility to install ghostscript, and the library requires ghostscript.

I've researched a lot, but couldn't fin a solution with this limitations...

Comment: Yes.. I make the request to install Ghostscript, but I was rejected... 

I will try with the FPDI, but still I don't understand all the documentation, thank you so much @KJ 

Comment: Thank you so much, @KJ, I was reading the documentation and is very useful for me, now I'm testing this tool and It seems to work in my develop server, I'll see if this tool can be deployed on production server.

Thank you very much, you're a crack!!